# Dragon book compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, cmd

Im studying compilers and im trying to run the compiler of the dragon book, I downloaded the source code from the page and follow all the instructions on the book

```
javac lexer/* .java
javac symbols/* .java
javac inter/* .java
javac parser/* .java
javac main/* .java
```

then run

```
java main.Main
```

and enter the  name of the test file the cmd prompt the following errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: near line 1: syntax error
   at parser.Parser.error(Parser.java:15)
   at parser.Parser.match(Parser.java:19)
   at parser.Parser.block(Parser.java:29)
   at parser.Parser.program(Parser.java:23)
   at main.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

and since I downloaded the code from the dragon book page (http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/) I dont think there is any errors there, I even checked the code with the book and is the same. Sorry if this is like a noob question but any idea what im doing wrong??

Comment: javac uses the full java class name e.g: javac lexer.java and java uses the full qualified class name. Make sure you have compiled all the classes needed. Also read the code of 'main'. does it need any cmd line args?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Nazgul, no, `javac` happily compiles multiple Java files when feeding it `*.java`

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Java source code at the link you provided, it appears that the "dragon front" parser expects to read its input from standard input ... not from a file whose name you supply on standard input.  Try this:

```
    java main.Main < your_input_file
```